# Setting a UILabel on the right side of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. I cannot use `XIB` or Interface builder. So I need to do this programmatically.

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *countLabel;

@end
```

I need the titleLabel and the countLabel to on the same line, with the countLabel on the right edge with a margin.

In the `layoutSubViews` method of `CustomTableViewCell` I have

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  const CGFloat HorizontalMargin = 10;
  const CGFloat VerticalMargin = 4;

  CGFloat x = HorizontalMargin;
  CGFloat y = VerticalMargin;
  CGSize textSize = [self.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font];
  CGFloat width = textSize.width;
  CGFloat height = self.contentView.frame.size.height - (2 * VerticalMargin);
  self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

  x += width + HorizontalMargin;
  textSize = [self.countLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.countLabel.font];
  width = textSize.width;
  CGFloat countL = 400;     
  self.countLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - 2*HorizontalMargin-width, y, width, height);
}
```

I can see the countLabel in the `XCode` visual debugger, but when I run it on my device, I cannot see the countLabel on the right side.

Comment: You should set up your cell template in Interface Builder and control the layout using AutoLayout constraints.

Comment: Where did you add those label to the cell's view?

Comment: try this CGRectMake(0, y, width, height)

Comment: Don't want to use IB and Autolayouts?